# Is window.location = example.com?q=<user input> susceptible to XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss

Let's say I have the following code:

```
//--get the value that was passed in via a query string parameter
var passedInQueryStringValue = getQueryStringValueFor("someKey");
//--append the value to the window.location as such:
window.location = "https://example.com?q=" + passedInQueryStringValue ;
```

Is this susceptible to XSS (or any other attack for that matter)? Let's assume that example.com properly handled whatever value for q gets sent over as that isn't the part I'm interested in here.

Something feels fishy here but I'm not positive there is a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on what example.com does with the querystring q

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, I want to assume that example.com handles everything just fine. I'm really trying to determine whether you can do anything malicious via "userInput" (like run script on the client or manipulating the path).

Comment: What you are doing in the above answer is allowing a user to pass any string to another website via a querystring. It is up to the developer of a website to make sure that inputs supplied by any means that is open to editing by an external source as possibly malicious.

Comment: I agree -- example.com needs to be able to handle this in the same way that I could just type google.com?q=<something malicious> and Google needs to handle it.

I'll update my question to make the input come from a query string parameter instead of a textbox as I think that changes the nature of the question to what I was actually going for. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @jakejgordon why does that change the nature of the question?

Comment: @GuyT if I'm updating window.location = <some value that is at least partially a function of a passed in query string parameter> then other people can post links to example.com?q=<something malicious>, and if someone goes to that link then perhaps something bad will happen. If q=<some value from a textbox on the form> then there would only be a problem if the user on that page put something bad in the textbox. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jakejgordon it does, but is not complete. Based on where the information comes from, one could still link to a page where the data is loaded into the textbox (or just displayed). This data may be harmful and therefore could contain malicious code. Check https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/persistent-xss/  :)

Comment: @GuyT Can you help me clarify my question then since I think I'm leading people down the wrong track. I'm trying to say "the only code we should care about is these two lines -- is there a vulnerability or not?". Let's assume example.com has no issues and the value of the "q" is not displayed on the page anywhere -- it's only used in these two lines of JavaScript.

Comment: @jakejgordon if it is not used and example.com has no issues, based on your assumptions, then no, it is not harmful :) On the other hand, if it is not used at all why should one implement a feature like this? In the provided example, if this would be a vulnerability, how can example.com prevent this?

Comment: @GuyT For clarification, the value of "passedInQueryStringValue" IS used: it is appended to the query string that window.location is being set to. I.e. the browser will submit a subsequent HTTP request... so I want to make sure that I'm not exposing the client to a code injection or open redirect vulnerability.

Comment: @jakejgordon as long as example.com has not vulnerabilities, not.

Answer (score -1):

Per Adrian and @GuyT, this code is safe and is not susceptible to XSS or code injection.

example.com must of course not do anything silly with the value of q (like print it out as HTML) - but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: Please feel free to offer a more clear answer if this is not the right answer. I see I'm getting downvotes but I'm trying to do do everything I can to make my question and the answer as clear s possible for the community.

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. It may not be that detailed, but it is correct.